# List comprehension with dataframe condition; ValueError: Item wrong length

Tags: python, pandas, list-comprehension, valueerror

I am trying to use list comprehension to create a list of DataFrames where the item that I append is the `DataFrame[condition = True]`. However, I get a Value Error:

```
list_of_dataframes = [df0[(df0['Names'].values == my_list_of_names[i])] for i in range(len(my_list_of_names))]
```

> File
>   "/home/josep/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py",
>   line 2986, in **getitem**
>       **return self._getitem_bool_array(key)**
>
> File
>   "/home/josep/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py",
>   line 3033, in _getitem_bool_array
>       **"Item wrong length %d instead of %d." % (len(key), len(self.index))**
>
> **ValueError: Item wrong length 233 instead of 234.**

For a list comprehension, the syntax goes like:

```
new_list = []
for i in old_list:
    if filter(i):
        new_list.append(expressions(i))
```

Which is rewritten as:`new_list = [expression(i) for i in old_list if filter(i)]`

So, now my `for` bucle is:

```
my_list_of_names = pd.DataFrame('0': ['Jou', 'Lara'])
d = {'Names': ['John', 'Lara', 'Ari', 'Jou'], 'col2': [1, 2, 2, 2], 'col3': [1, 2 ,3, 4], 'col4': [2,1,1,1,], 'col5': [2,1,0,0], 'col6': [2,1,3,1]}
df0 = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

list_of_dataframes = []
for i in range(len(my_list_of_names)):
    df_i = df0[(df0['Names'].values ==
                  my_list_of_names.values[i])]
    list_of_dataframes.append(df_i)
```

Which can be written as:

```
list_of_dataframes = [df0[(df0['Names'].values == 
 my_list_of_names.values[i])] for i in range(len(my_list_of_names))]
```

And **this works completely fine**. But if I try to simplify my code by changing the type of `my_list_of_names`, which is a DataFrame, to a **list** type:

```
my_list_of_names2 = ['Jou', 'Lara']  # IS A LIST
list_of_df = [df0[(df0['Names'].values ==
                   my_list_of_names2[measure])
                  ] for measure in range(len(my_list_of_names2))]
```

It raises a Value Error:

> runcell(7, '~/sample.py')
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "~/sample.py",
>   line 263, in 
>       for measure in range(len(my_list_of_names2))]
>
> File "~/sample.py",
>   line 263, in 
>       for measure in range(len(my_list_of_names2))]
>
> File
>   "~home/josep/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py",
>   line 2986, in **getitem**
>       return self._getitem_bool_array(key)
>
> File
>   "/home/josep/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py",
>   line 3033, in _getitem_bool_array
>       "Item wrong length %d instead of %d." % (len(key), len(self.index))
>
> ValueError: Item wrong length 233 instead of 234.

NOTE: The real list and dataframe are different, but for the sake of the question I thought to be easier to put shorter ones.

Comment: And what is your problem? You know the syntax, apply it. If you have a problem with your implementation, then ask.

Comment: What is your question, exactly?

Comment: @JuanJavierSantosOchoa thank you. I think now is much clearer. I don't know what I had in my mind when I posted it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might not be the best solution, but I believe it solves your direct example.

```py
for name in my_list_of_names:
    df_i = df0[df0['Names'] == name]
    list_of_dataframes.append(df_i)
```